# Reload frames using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to reload a frame (not iframe) using jQuery, but I'm not succeeding. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


    <frameset cols="*,360" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="2">
        <frame src="index-coding.html" class="reload" name="desktop" noresize>
        <frame src="index-coding.html" class="reload" name="mobile" noresize>
    </frameset>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function setupRefresh() { setTimeout("refreshPage();", 5000); }
function refreshPage() { $('.reload' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; }); }   
});
</script>
</html>
```

Is there a reason it would work for iframes, but not frames?

Edit: I readjusted the html so it uses iframes, instead of frames - still having the same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<iframe src="index-coding.html" frameborder="0" class="reload" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: calc(100% - 360px); height: 100%; "></iframe>

<iframe src="index-coding.html" frameborder="0" class="reload" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 360px; height: 100%;"></iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function setupRefresh() { setTimeout("refreshPage();", 5000); }
function refreshPage() { $('.reload' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; }); }   
});
</script>
</html>
```

I fixed it by using this code:

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                // refreshiframe();
                break;
            case "focus":
                refreshiframe();
                break;
        }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
})


function refreshiframe() {
$('.reload').attr('src', $('.reload').attr('src'));
}
```

Comment: Frames were cool in like 2005, do you seriously have to use them? Isn't there some better way?

Comment: I could use a better way, but was just wondering if it could be done with normal frames.

Comment: Where are you calling `setupRefresh()`?